# How to shortcut simple mathematical "solution" in python?

Tags: python

```
num = 0
num = num + 2
num = num - 5
num = num * 88
num = num / 11
print(num)
```

Hi guys, That's an example of a code that I've been asked "what is the best way to shortcut it ?" or "write a shorthand version of this code"
I did it like this:

```
num = 0
num += 2
num -= 5
num *= 88
num /= 11
print(num)
```

But I believe there is a better solution ?

Comment: What's meant by "shortcut"? Are they asking how it can be simplified?

Comment: Yes, I believe short hand version of something is to simplify it  :)

Comment: Here you go: `print(-24.)`

Comment: Haha, clever, but that's not a solution :)

Comment: @jessiehitech Why not?

Comment: That's sophistry, not mathematical solution in python.

Comment: You keep talking about this mysterious "solution" but you still didn't define what you mean with that.

Comment: What I did is kind of solution, that's why I put that as an example. I'm new here and on python so it's ok if you don't understand me :)

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
(num + 2 - 5) * 88 / 11
```

Or if you want it to work for a different set of numbers, you could have a function:

```
def apply(num, add, sub, mul, div):
    return (num + add - sub) * mul / div
```

Then you can:

```
print(apply(0, 2, 5, 88, 11))
```

Answer (score -1):

To simply:

```
num = 0
num = num + 2
num = num - 5
num = num * 88
num = num / 11
print(num)
```

into a smaller answer would be:

```
num = 0
num += 2
num -= 5
num *= 88
num /= 11
print(num)
```

Just like how you already did.

Python manual link: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=augmented%20assignment%20statements